# How can I conditionally include a file based on build configuration in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, build-rules

I have an Xcode project with a large number of targets where I would like to include a settings bundle for apps built under the Ad-hoc and Debug configurations, but not under the Release configuration.

Build Phases don't seem to allow for making themselves conditional on configuration (they can obviously be conditional on target, but doubling the number of targets in the project would make it completely unusable).

That leaves writing a custom Build Rule. My plan is to exclude the Settings.bundle from all targets, and create a build rule that conditionally copies it into the product package, but applicable examples are really hard to find.

The build rule I've started has the Process setting set to "Source files with names matching:" and Settings.bundle as the name. The Using setting is "Custom script:".

My custom script is as follows (with the caveat that my bash scripting is on a cargo cult level):

```
if [${CONFIGURATION} = 'Debug'] then
    cp -r ${INPUT_FILE_PATH} ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/.
fi
```

Finally, I have `${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/Settings.bundle` listed as an output file.

Since I'm here, it should be obvious that it's not working. My first question is whether there is somewhere I can view the output of the build rules as the execute to make sure that 1) it's actually being executed and that 2) I don't have a stupid syntax error somewhere.

Also, what's the proper location (in the form of an environment variable) to copy the output to?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

For each target for which you want to conditionally include the settings bundle, choose its Project from the source list, choose the target, and switch to the "Build Phases" tab.

Click the "Add Build Phase" button and choose "Add Run Script".

Then enter the following for the script:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]; then
    cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Settings.bundle" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used to approach to manage firebase project plist files for different configurations.

Answer (score 53):

I know this question has been answered already, and the answer was very helpful to me, but I wanted to throw my own modified solution out there as well.

My requirement was to have different settings bundles for different build configurations, rather than just not including it at release. Assuming a simplistic approach of only *Debug* and *Release* configurations, here's how to do it:

Start by adding 2 settings bundles to the project, named `Settings-debug.bundle` and `Settings-release.bundle` and then remove these files from the **Copy Bundle Resources** build phase. Next add a user defined build setting called `SETTINGS_BUNDLE`, which has different values for each configuration:

```
Debug        ${PROJECT_DIR}/relative/path/to/Settings-debug.bundle
Release      ${PROJECT_DIR}/relative/path/to/Settings-release.bundle
```

Next add a run-script build phase (after **Copy Bundle Resources**) named **Copy Settings Bundle** with a modified version of the script in Frank's solution.

```
cp -r "${SETTINGS_BUNDLE}/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Settings.bundle"
```

The difference here is that the copied bundle is always named **Settings.bundle** regardless of the source name.

You then need to add another build phase script to prevent code signing errors when the only changes are in the settings bundles. It forces the code signing step to occur on every build. This should run **before** the *Compile Source Files* build phase. I called mine **Force Codesign**.

```
touch "${PROJECT_DIR}/relative/path/to/main.m"
```

Comment: Great solution for a debug-only application preference pane in the built-in settings app, which is what I was after.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also write:

cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/settings_bundle/Settings-${CONFIGURATION}.bundle/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Settings.bundle"

 This will let you avoid adding any user defined build entry and will use the files 'settings_bundle/Settings-Debug.bundle', 'settings_bundle/Settings-Release.bundle', etc

Comment: As SETTINGS_BUNDLE variables, I used ${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Resources/Settings.bundle

Comment: And instead of looking for the files in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase to have them removed, simply remove any target membership for the bundle files in the File inspector. Quicker.

Answer (score 31):

For complied sources, there is a poorly documented user defined build setting that can be added. Files can be both excluded and included from compilation

Go to your target's Build Settings > Tap the + button > Add User-Defined Setting

The key is either `INCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` or `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES`

The value is a space separated list of file paths

See reference:
http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Jun/msg00153.html

Comment: I can confirm that adding EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES is still working (and still undocumented) in Xcode 8.2..x

Answer (score 11):

(Tested with **Xcode 9.3**)

I can't find when Xcode included this feature but `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` is now directly available in `Build Settings > Build Options > Excluded Source File Names`.

So you no longer need to create a `User-Defined Setting`.

See below:
[image]

It will automatically add this line in your `.pbxproj`. 
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason to use explicit exclusion with `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` instead of explicit inclusion via `INCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES`? When I use inclusion, it straight up doesn't work. Tried with a raw json file and an xcassets file

Comment: Apple says `This setting [INCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES] is only useful when combined with EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` Is what you say related to this ? Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference#Included-Source-File-Names

Answer (score 7):

Settings.bundle is always copied into destination area no matter whether Release or Debug configuration. So, maybe you need the following code:

```
if [ ${CONFIGURATION} == "Release" ]; then
    rm -rf ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Settings.bundle
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I am no shell script expert but I think you need space between the square brackets and the condition. Also, quoting the variables may help:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Debug" ] then
    cp -r "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}" "${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}"/.
fi
```

As for the location, I use `"$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR"/"$FULL_PRODUCT_NAME"` for the root of my OS X app bundle.

Comment: This gives me syntax errors when I build. Frank's solution, copied and pasted, worked perfectly.

Comment: To be wholly fair, this guy's answer was posted three months earlier.