# Setting release and debug config files iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm releasing an app on iOS and I'm tired of remembering to change my staging urls to production urls before making the release .ipa in Xcode.

In Android Studio I can configure different release and debug files to be used.

Assuming I have my urls in a file named Config.plist is there a way to specify different files to pull in for a release or debug build in Xcode?

Comment: The only way I found is to have URLs to be set via environment variable that has different values for Debug/Release

Comment: You can add your URLs in your Info.plist, and in your Target/Build Settings/Packaging, select the info.plist you want for each target (Debug and Release).

Comment: You could also use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496476/how-can-i-conditionally-include-a-file-based-on-build-configuration-in-xcode (if yours URLs are in a file), or just write a "#ifdef RELEASE or #ifdef DEBUG" that you added in your macros for each scheme.