# IOS Static Framework with resources inside

Tags: ios, frameworks, uiimageview, xib

I'm trying to create a framework that keeps some common code I use around in my projects.
I found online tutorials and managed to create a framework but I still have one problem related to resources (xibs, images, etc).

Let's say I have a `MainViewController.xib` which has a `UIImageView` using a `test.png`. All these are in my framework package.

When I use the framework in another project, I add it to the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase. The problem is that the xib is only accessible using a path like `dummy.framework/Resources/MainViewController.xib` and the `UIImageView` inside can't load `test.png`.

It seems that the UIImageView will try to load the png from the root of the bundle, and not from the relative folder where the xib is also stored.

Has anybody managed to create a framework with code and resources and use it in another project?

Comment: Hi andrei, can you please tell me how you add the .bundle file into framework directory... i am not able to do that. there may be some mistake in my shell script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

When you compile the app, the bundle is generated with the resources of the "main" project, ignoring the resources in linked frameworks. This includes images, xib's, plist's, etc. (anything that isn't a source file)

What you need to do is add those resources to your main project so that they are available for use inside your application, not the happiest way around it but it'll work.

Comment: Well, the resources are copied, but in a sub folder.

Comment: This is the closest answer to the real facts. You can however force xcode to copy resources from a framework, but they will be placed in a subfolder in main bundle. This makes loading them a pain in the ass.

Comment: @doozMen Care to explain how?

Answer (score 14):

I know this is an old thread, but to keep new people from making the same mistakes here is a note:

As of Xcode 6 and iOS8, Apple has a fully supported first party Dynamic Framework solution built in. For more information look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014509-SW14

But the short of it is, create a new project and choose the Cocoa Touch Framework template.

Comment: All good and well, but have you actually managed to include image resources in a Dynamic Framework created in Xcode 6. I've tried everything myself, but can't get it working! Seems to be very little documentation from Apple on it.

Comment: Yes. its been fairly simple but maybe not obvious. Simple include your images in your framework like normal, but to load them, you need to reference the bundle of your framework. So `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.<#company#>.<#framework#>"];`

Comment: You don't need a fool around with creating a bundle or anything. Xcode's framework handles that for you. But you do have to load them from that default bundle. I find it useful to create an NSBundle category with a shortcut for the frameworks category.

Comment: Also, for future issues, you'll have a lot of success finding help and documentation if you search for Mac frameworks or Cocoa Touch frameworks. They're new to us iOS developers, but they're not new to the world. There was lots of a good Mac documentation out there that aligned and thats how I found out that they create their own bundle.

Comment: Yeah got this working with `imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection`. Sending inBundle: `[NSBundle bundleWithClass[self class]]` or whatever is appropriate given where I'm using the image.

Comment: Yes, that method is AWESOME! Sadly its iOS8 only. But if you go with Apple's new Dynamic Framework option you're tied to iOS8 anyway. And I think its safe to make that decision for new developments.

Comment: Crap. you're right. About the method anyway... I was of the opinion that frameworks were compatible with iOS7 however? That was certainly how Apple advertised them. Unfortunately working for clients who expect their products to still run on iOS7 my hands are tied as far as only supporting iOS8. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Apple's frameworks definitely do not work on iOS7. But you'll need the same bundle mindset to support assets with a static library. This might help https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework

Comment: Do they not work, or do they just refuse to submit them? Because We've had projects with Apple's frameworks working on iOS 7 devices under our enterprise license...

Comment: Everytime I try to get it to build I get an error that says Dynamic Frameworks aren't supported in this version of iOS.

Comment: If you can show me how to get a framework working with iOS7 you would make my year

Comment: Yeah we hadn't actually tried submitting until now. Turns out you can get it running, and even distribute enterprise builds for iOS7 using the new frameworks. But when apples checking your build for upload to the store it rejects it. A couple of guys from work were at WWDC where they said it'd work on iOS7, looked back and they'd removed 45 minutes of video from the talk on it!

Comment: Hi Ryan. Any suggestions how to use the image from a framework within a storyboard or xib? When I try, I get an error: **Could not load the "<ImageName>" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "<BundleName>"**

Comment: Don't have any relevant experience with Storyboards. Try to keep those out of frameworks and rely on code only instead. Probably worth creating your own question on StackOverflow for that specific question.

Answer (score 8):

I created a framework target and to access images inside its asset catalog I did the following:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_NAME_HERE" inBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] compatibleWithTraitCollection:[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithDisplayScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you I've waste a lot of time trying to find a solution for it. and this one worked :)

Comment: This one's for dynamic frameworks though, not static ones, since for static frameworks `bundleForClass:self.class` returns the main app bundle.

Answer (score 5):

I don't manually manage frameworks anymore but use and [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25174719/1049134) [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) instead.

---

*Original answer:*

1. Use the [fake framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) @wattson12 mentioned. It will compile and save the resources as well.
2. Inspired by [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668021/include-exclude-resources-depending-on-scheme), add this to your target to copy the resources to your app:

   ```
   SOURCE_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/MYFramework.framework/Resources/"
   TARGET_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/MYFrameworkResources.bundle"
   mkdir -p $TARGET_PATH
   cp -R $SOURCE_PATH $TARGET_PATH
   ```

You could also just drag the framework to your Copy Resources step, but then you'll be adding unnecessary headers and compiled code as well.

**Edit**

To use these resources from IB, for instance a png file, replace:

```
MyImage
```

by:

```
MYFrameworkResources.bundle/MyImage.png
```

It will preview a broken image icon but will work when running.

Load a Nib from code:

```
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"MYFrameworkResources.bundle/MyNib" ...
```

Finally you can add these methods in a NSBundle category to ease access to Nib resources that my be in your main bundle or in MYFrameworkResources.bundle:

```
@implementation NSBundle (MyCategory)

+ (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name
                       ofType:(NSString *)extension
{
    // First try with the main bundle
    NSBundle * mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString * path = [mainBundle pathForResource:name
                                           ofType:extension];
    if (path)
    {
        return path;
    }

    // Otherwise try with other bundles
    NSBundle * bundle;
    for (NSString * bundlePath in [mainBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bundle"
                                                          inDirectory:nil])
    {
        bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
        path = [bundle pathForResource:name
                                ofType:extension];
        if (path)
        {
            return path;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"No path found for: %@ (.%@)", name, extension);
    return nil;
}

+ (NSArray *)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name
                    owner:(id)owner
                  options:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    // First try with the main bundle
    NSBundle * mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    if ([mainBundle pathForResource:name
                             ofType:@"nib"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Loaded Nib named: '%@' from mainBundle", name);
        return [mainBundle loadNibNamed:name
                                  owner:owner
                                options:options];
    }

    // Otherwise try with other bundles
    NSBundle * bundle;
    for (NSString * bundlePath in [mainBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bundle"
                                                          inDirectory:nil])
    {
        bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
        if ([bundle pathForResource:name
                             ofType:@"nib"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Loaded Nib named: '%@' from bundle: '%@' ", name, bundle.bundleIdentifier);
            return [bundle loadNibNamed:name
                                  owner:owner
                                options:options];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Couldn't load Nib named: %@", name);
    return nil;
}

@end
```

It will first look into your application bundle and then in MYFrameworkResources.bundle, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but interface builder still won't properly detect the resources

Comment: Are you having problems with the images? (prepending the path is enough) or with the Nibs? You can also check your build directory to see where the resources are getting copied inside your app.

Answer (score 4):

In order to load an image from a dynamic framework in **Swift 3**:

`UIImage(named: "name", in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: nil)`

Comment: It works perfect. What was my scenario, I was using my custom framework with assets but not able to use assets images. But this worked for me

Comment: The original question is about using recourses from **static** frameworks

Answer (score 1):

Basic frameworks do not include most kinds of resources, to include resources use [this "fake" framework library](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework)

You end up with a .embeddedframework folder which contains the actual framework, but also includes any resources which you add to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase. Ive used it to include xibs, core data models, images, and plists

Comment: Yes, but if you have (in the framework) a xib that uses a resource that is also in the framework (a image let's say). Will you be able to load the xib in the test application?

Comment: I dont have that project in front of me but I'm pretty sure that would be ok, give it a shot...

Comment: I've concluded that what I want to achieve is not really possible. Due to Interface Builder's inability to display images that are in subfolders (they work on runtime though) it's really not feasible to deliver any resources in a bundle form. Best way would be to simply add a zip along with the static library and the user can use that folder in its project.

Comment: You can reference resources nested inside subfolders from IB by adding the path: MyResources.bundle/image.png. It won't look nice inside IB but it will work

Answer (score -1):

As of Xcode 7 we can now use Asset Catalogs. In my experiments I've found that u can reference files in the same workspace bit different projects removing the need to micro manage assets in build phases or worrying about targets.

Comment: This answer is unrelated to the question