# Texture Atlas can not be found in iOS framework

Tags: ios, swift

Evrything was working fine until I tried to put my assets (sprite sheets) inside an iOS framework. I'm using Swift 3.0

To lighten my Xcode project, I have decided to put my assets: sprite sheets produced by TexturePacker inside a framework. When they are include in the main project, as internal ressources, everything is working fine. But when I put my atlas inside a framework, the code is compiling fine, no error, the app is running fine on the physical device (an iPad) but I have a red cross instead of my sprites. I get the following error message from the console:

2016-11-02 15:35:02.166 Test Puzzles[310:42458] Texture Atlas 'Statiques' cannot be found.
2016-11-02 15:35:02.392 Test Puzzles[310:42458] Texture Atlas 'Puzzle0' cannot be found.
2016-11-02 15:35:02.393 Test Puzzles[310:42458] Texture Atlas 'Puzzle1' cannot be found.

etc, etc (until 41)

I have put the public keyword before my class and all the functions called from the main project. Here is an example...

```
import SpriteKit


public class Statiques {

public init() {

}

// sprite names
let DANCING1 = "Dancing1"
let DANCING2 = "Dancing2"
let PUZZLE0  = "Puzzle0"
let PUZZLE1  = "Puzzle1"
let PUZZLE10 = "Puzzle10"
let PUZZLE11 = "Puzzle11"
let PUZZLE12 = "Puzzle12"
let PUZZLE13 = "Puzzle13"
let PUZZLE14 = "Puzzle14"
let PUZZLE15 = "Puzzle15"
let PUZZLE16 = "Puzzle16"
let PUZZLE17 = "Puzzle17"
let PUZZLE18 = "Puzzle18"
let PUZZLE19 = "Puzzle19"
let PUZZLE2  = "Puzzle2"
let PUZZLE20 = "Puzzle20"
let PUZZLE21 = "Puzzle21"
let PUZZLE22 = "Puzzle22"
let PUZZLE23 = "Puzzle23"
let PUZZLE24 = "Puzzle24"
let PUZZLE25 = "Puzzle25"
let PUZZLE26 = "Puzzle26"
let PUZZLE27 = "Puzzle27"
let PUZZLE28 = "Puzzle28"
let PUZZLE29 = "Puzzle29"
let PUZZLE3  = "Puzzle3"
let PUZZLE30 = "Puzzle30"
let PUZZLE31 = "Puzzle31"
let PUZZLE32 = "Puzzle32"
let PUZZLE33 = "Puzzle33"
let PUZZLE34 = "Puzzle34"
let PUZZLE35 = "Puzzle35"
let PUZZLE36 = "Puzzle36"
let PUZZLE37 = "Puzzle37"
let PUZZLE38 = "Puzzle38"
let PUZZLE39 = "Puzzle39"
let PUZZLE4  = "Puzzle4"
let PUZZLE40 = "Puzzle40"
let PUZZLE41 = "Puzzle41"
let PUZZLE5  = "Puzzle5"
let PUZZLE6  = "Puzzle6"
let PUZZLE7  = "Puzzle7"
let PUZZLE8  = "Puzzle8"
let PUZZLE9  = "Puzzle9"


// load texture atlas
let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Statiques")


// individual texture objects
public func Dancing1() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(DANCING1) }
public func Dancing2() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(DANCING2) }
public func Puzzle0() -> SKTexture  { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE0) }
public func Puzzle1() -> SKTexture  { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE1) }
public func Puzzle10() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE10) }
public func Puzzle11() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE11) }
public func Puzzle12() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE12) }
public func Puzzle13() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE13) }
public func Puzzle14() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE14) }
public func Puzzle15() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE15) }
public func Puzzle16() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE16) }
public func Puzzle17() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE17) }
public func Puzzle18() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE18) }
public func Puzzle19() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE19) }
public func Puzzle2() -> SKTexture  { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE2) }
public func Puzzle20() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE20) }
public func Puzzle21() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE21) }
public func Puzzle22() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE22) }
public func Puzzle23() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE23) }
public func Puzzle24() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE24) }
public func Puzzle25() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE25) }
public func Puzzle26() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE26) }
public func Puzzle27() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE27) }
public func Puzzle28() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE28) }
public func Puzzle29() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE29) }
public func Puzzle3() -> SKTexture  { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE3) }
public func Puzzle30() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE30) }
public func Puzzle31() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE31) }
public func Puzzle32() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE32) }
public func Puzzle33() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE33) }
public func Puzzle34() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE34) }
public func Puzzle35() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE35) }
public func Puzzle36() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE36) }
public func Puzzle37() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE37) }
public func Puzzle38() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE38) }
public func Puzzle39() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE39) }
public func Puzzle4() -> SKTexture  { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE4) }
public func Puzzle40() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE40) }
public func Puzzle41() -> SKTexture { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE41) }
public func Puzzle5() -> SKTexture  { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE5) }
public func Puzzle6() -> SKTexture  { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE6) }
public func Puzzle7() -> SKTexture  { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE7) }
public func Puzzle8() -> SKTexture  { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE8) }
public func Puzzle9() -> SKTexture  { return textureAtlas.textureNamed(PUZZLE9) }


// texture arrays for animations
public func Dancing() -> [SKTexture] {
    return [
        Dancing1(),
        Dancing2()
    ]
}

public func Puzzle() -> [SKTexture] {
    return [
        Puzzle0(),
        Puzzle1(),
        Puzzle2(),
        Puzzle3(),
        Puzzle4(),
        Puzzle5(),
        Puzzle6(),
        Puzzle7(),
        Puzzle8(),
        Puzzle9(),
        Puzzle10(),
        Puzzle11(),
        Puzzle12(),
        Puzzle13(),
        Puzzle14(),
        Puzzle15(),
        Puzzle16(),
        Puzzle17(),
        Puzzle18(),
        Puzzle19(),
        Puzzle20(),
        Puzzle21(),
        Puzzle22(),
        Puzzle23(),
        Puzzle24(),
        Puzzle25(),
        Puzzle26(),
        Puzzle27(),
        Puzzle28(),
        Puzzle29(),
        Puzzle30(),
        Puzzle31(),
        Puzzle32(),
        Puzzle33(),
        Puzzle34(),
        Puzzle35(),
        Puzzle36(),
        Puzzle37(),
        Puzzle38(),
        Puzzle39(),
        Puzzle40(),
        Puzzle41()
    ]
}


}
```

From my main app, I call the framework with this code:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import Framework_Dancing


class GameScene1: GameScene {

// not useful code for this problem is missing here...

let sheet = Statiques()

let sprite_dancing1 = SKPuzzleAnim(texture: sheet.Dancing1())
let sprite_dancing2 = SKPuzzleAnim(texture: sheet.Dancing2())
```

My framework is 130 MB, wich let me think the assets are correctly included inside it, I get no error from the compiler, what am I missing with the framework ? As soon as I put the assets into the main project, without the framework, everything is OK.

All the atlas has been generated by TexturePacker.

Here is a screen copy of my Xcode project with the code from the framework:

[image: Screen copy]

Thanks for your help,

Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reply I got from the creators of TexturePacker:

"as far as I know the SKTextureAtlas constructor always searches its atlas file in the main app, even if it is called in the framework code. I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, you would have to ask Apple. I'm sorry, but I can't help you with this issue :-/
Best regards,
Joachim"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you get the error because you are looking for the assets in your main project, not in the framework project.

For example if you want to show an UIImage thats stored in a framework you would have to write this

```
let image = UIImage(named: "SomeImage", in: Bundle(identifier: "FrameworkBundleID"), compatibleWith: nil)
```

You can read more about this here

[cocoa touch framework assets not visible in App Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782706/cocoa-touch-framework-assets-not-visible-in-app-project)

The problem is that SKNode/SKSpriteNode etc do not have a similar initialiser, so I am not sure it will work.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, the problem may be because I've created the framework as a sub project of my main app and not as an independent one. I'm going to try this way.According my tests, the swift files from the framework clearly not see the atlasc datas inside this same framework.

Comment: Yeah not sure about that sub project way. Keep us posted