# iOS static framework with resources without using separate resources bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I have a static library project, in which now I need to include some resources, so I want to turn it into a framework. I need to include those resources **inside** framework, without the need to rely on separate resource bundle, for several reasons:
-to prevent the resources from tampering with
-for simplicity of usage of my framework

Now, in every tutorial I've read, the resources were supplied as separate bundle. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180113/ios-static-framework-with-resources-inside) answer states that it isn't possible, but it's almost 5 years old. Has anything changed in that matter? Is it possible to include resources inside framework, without exposing them to framework's users? I am using Objective-C and deployment target is iOS 9.

Comment: Your question is tagged as being about a static library but you're also asking about a framework.  With a framework, it "just works".

Comment: @PhillipMills I already have a static library project, but now I need to include some resources in it. Edited original question

Comment: Create a real framework project (or target in your current project), include your sources and resources, and build that instead of your static library.  (I actually did this about a month ago for a large library.  It's not terribly difficult.)

Comment: @PhillipMills I added "Cocoa Touch Framework" target to my project, it created a header file. In That header I try to include headers from my static library, but it gives me an error: "Include of non-modular header inside framework module". In Build Settings I already set "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to YES, but the error remains.

Comment: Also, the headers from static lib are exposed as public in Build Phases -> Headers

Answer (score 0):

Apple has introduced cocoa touch framework, which lets you include resources as well.

Comment: I have an existing static library project, but now I need to include some resources as well. How to turn it into a Cocoa Touch Framework?